# Named Arguments do not work in a string with conditional logic

Tags: python

I have a multiline string with an in-line if condition as follows:

```
my_string=  """
        Hello my name is """ + ('John' if client == "j123" else 'Mary') + """

        Good bye. """
```

However, when I insert a named parameter, it does not seem to properly treat it. With some testing I found out that removing the IF from the string would allow the named parameters to work

```
my_string=  """
        Hello my name is """ + ('John' if client == "j123" else 'Mary') + """

        %(msg_key)s

        Good bye. """ % {"msg_key" : "Additional msg"}
```

Is there a specific reason why this won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```py
my_string=  """
        Hello my name is """ + ['John' if client == "j123" else 'Mary'][0] + """

        Good bye. """
```

Answer (score 0):

With f-string it would be more effective:

```py
my_string =  f"""
        Hello my name is {'John' if client == "j123" else 'Mary'}

        {msg_key}

        Good bye. """.format(msg_key="Additional msg")
```

Comment: I did not know that you can write the if condition in curly brackets. Does this technique have a particular name? Many thanks

Comment: @test, its a normal python inline if statement and you can combine the result in any f-string curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

msg_key is not a variable, it just identifies the placeholder in the string.

This works:

```
my_string=  """
        Hello my name is """ + ('John' if client == "j123" else 'Mary') + """

        %(msg_key)s

        Good bye. """ % {"msg_key" : "Additional msg"}
```

Comment: thnx that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to opt for a cleaner method as follows, shifting any logic to the named arguments rather than leaving them in-line.

```
my_string=  """
    Hello my name is {name}

    {something_else}

    Good bye. """.format(
      name=("John" if client_code == "j" else "Mary"),
      something_else="Additional Message"
    )
```